# 11DB Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I a rookie in OBjective C. I am writing a login feature in Xcode. But it crashes. Seeking for help!

2016-02-06 03:14:09.331 Login[3466:392205] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b81f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001015fbdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b81e7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   UIKit                               0x00000001022e4eff -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 499
4   UIKit                               0x00000001020bfc16 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
5   UIKit                               0x00000001020c0542 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
6   UIKit                               0x00000001020c08a0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
7   UIKit                               0x00000001020c1013 -[UIViewController view] + 27
8   UIKit                               0x0000000101f9a51c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
9   UIKit                               0x0000000101f9ac05 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
10  UIKit                               0x0000000101fac4a5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
11  UIKit                               0x0000000101f26396 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
12  UIKit                               0x0000000101f2c9c3 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1750
13  UIKit                               0x0000000101f29ba3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
14  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001048d9784 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001048d9af2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101aae011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101aa3f3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101aa33f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101aa2e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
20  UIKit                               0x0000000101f294f5 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
21  UIKit                               0x0000000101f2e30d UIApplicationMain + 171
22  Login                               0x00000001010fd33f main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001042a592d start + 1
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x5fc0d, 0x00000001045db286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001045db286 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001045a49f9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x000000010434ca44 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
    frame #3: 0x000000010414a051 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
    frame #4: 0x000000010416fac9 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 267
    frame #5: 0x00000001015fc046 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 103
    frame #6: 0x000000010416d26e libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x000000010416cef9 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x00000001015fbf5e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x0000000101aa2ec4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 676
    frame #10: 0x0000000101f294f5 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 402
    frame #11: 0x0000000101f2e30d UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
  * frame #12: 0x00000001010fd33f Login`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5eb02650) + 111 at main.m:14
    frame #13: 0x00000001042a592d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)

Comment: can you show your code like this ViewController *vc =  [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/licherry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/974CCEC5-9645-4EF7-8E26-7C2CDF92049F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FB88491F-B2B6-44EB-BF6D-98FA57B6ECE0/Login.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem,in Two ways:

**Option-1**

> regarding the nib name. Check the nib name spelling, it's correct, case sensitive.

**Option-2**

if option -1 does not work try this

1. Open XCode Target
2. Go to the "Build phases" tab
3. Click the "Copy bundle resources" section
4. Click the add button
5. Add the missing Nib file

then works fine

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/licherry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/974CCEC5-9645-4EF7-8E26‌​-7C2CDF92049F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FB88491F-B2B6-44EB-BF6D-98FA57B6‌​ECE0/Login.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController'' – wenjing li just now   edit   
Thanks!!! and Check the nib name spelling? do you mean the nib file spelling?

Comment: yes some time we made the small mistake also for example the correct name is `ViewController` but by mistake we assign `viewController`

Comment: thks so much really helped a lot!

Comment: @wenjingli -- tanx bro, if my answer is useful, please accept the tick mark , it is useful in future also